# Telling jQuery which (unique) div to do an action on

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My plan is to have lots of boxes (an undefined amount). When show box is clicked under a box, it shows that particular box.

I have some unique divs in my html. The div is made unique by:

```
<div id="box-<%=box.id%>"></div>
```

In my `application.js`, I have

```
$('.show-box > a').click(function(){
$('#box').show();
});
```

I obviously need to have the box-id in the `$('#box').show();` part but I'm unsure how to do that...

EDIT: adding more information

```
<div class="show-box">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box-<%= box.id  %>"></div>
```

The class is for styling.

Just to add, I know that the javascript link should link to an actual link. I'll fix that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `this` inside the handler to refer to the specific `.show-box > a` that was clicked.

So it depends on what the relationship is between that and the `box` element you want to display.

When you say *under*, if that means that it is a sibling to the `.show-box` element, you can [use `.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to traverse up from the `<a>`, then [use `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to traverse back to the `box`.

```
$('.show-box > a').click(function() {
      // "this" refers to the <a> that was clicked.
    $(this).parent().prev().show();
});
```

Ultimately, the correct solution depends on your actual HTML markup. If you provide that in your question, it would be helpful.

You could select by ID if you want, but it is often not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have added my HTML to the question. The box isn't a sibling. Under was the wrong word to use.

Comment: @GreenRails - I guess the question would be is there some consistent relationship between the position of the `.show-box` and its related `box`?

Comment: Ah ha! Since the box is underneath the link " $(this).parent().prev().show();" didn't work. Changing prev() to next() fixed it. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @GreenRails - Ah, siblings but in the other direction. :o) Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

On easy way would be to name your box ids after you a ids, or write another attribute into the a. For example if your a tag's ID was "anchor1", assign the corresponding div an id of "box-anchor1". Then, reference it like this:

```
$('.show-box > a').click(function(){ 
$('#box' + this.attr('id')).show(); 
});
```

Comment: The "a" doesn't have an ID. It's just a link that I can click for an action.

Answer (score 1):

If the box and the link that shows it are logically related, you can skip the whole unique ID business by using the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <!-- stuff in the box -->
  </div>
  <a href="#">Show</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div.container a").click(function() {
  $(this).prev().show(); // prev() will get the div.box element.
});
```

On the other hand, if they are not related structurally, you can use the fragment part of the URL to reference the box ID:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="box" id="box-1">...</div>
    <div class="box" id="box-2">...</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="boxtoggler" href="#box-1">Show Box 1</a>
    <a class="boxtoggler" href="#box-2">Show Box 2</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a.boxtoggler").click(function() {
    var boxId = $(this).attr("href");
    $(boxId).show();
});
```

Note how we're abusing the fact that the fragment section of a URL is preceded by a `#` character to make it into a css ID ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question, but if you want to show the clicked box:

```
$('.show-box > a').click(function(){
$(this).parents('.show-box').show();
});
```

Comment: I don't think that `show-box` is the same as the `box` that needs to be displayed. If it was, then the `<a>` element would be hidden as well, and you couldn't click it. :o)